# How to send the index of a for loop into the promise of a function in a Vue Resource call?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am looping through an object however in the asynchronous part the `i` variable is always five.

How can I maintain that value, or pass it into the function

```
getProductData: function() {
                var vm = this;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'].length; i++) {
                    var sku = vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['id'];
                    vm.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/models/api/productimage/' + sku).then(response => {
                        // get body data
                        vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['image_url'] = response.body['product_image_url'];
                        vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['price'] = response.body['price'];
                    }, response => {
                        vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['image_url'] = '';
                        vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['price'] = '';
                    });
                }
            }
```

I I do something like this:

`vm.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/models/api/productimage/' + sku).then((response, i) => ...`

then `i` is undefined

Who do I keep the index of the loop or should I go about it a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `let` to initialize variables in for loop when dealing with async operations. Similar things goes to having for loops in intervals. By using `let` you make sure you always have a unique variable assigned to `i`.

```
for (let i = 0, recommendationlength = vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'].length; i < recommendationlength; i++)
```

Little bonus, if you cache array length in the beginning you get a small performance boost :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```
var vm = this;  
vm.recommendataionResponse['recommendedItems'].forEach((item, i) => {
  var sku = vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['id'];
  vm.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/models/api/productimage/' + sku).then(response => {
    // get body data
    vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['image_url'] = response.body['product_image_url'];
    vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['price'] = response.body['price'];
  }, response => {
    vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['image_url'] = '';
    vm.recommendationResponse['recommendedItems'][i]['items'][0]['price'] = '';
  });
})
```

This way, since there is a unique scope for each `i` value, each `.then` callback will be able to reference the correct value.